# Is it possible to specify the DECIMAL scale and precision in sqoop type mapping?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to specify the column type mapping via the sqoop option:

```
 --map-column-hive <<FieldName>>=DECIMAL\(15,2\)
```

But this returns the error:

```
Column mapping should be the form key=value[,key=value]*
```

If I remove the scale and precision values (and the parenthesis), that works but it defaults to a DECIMAL(10,0).

I need to be able to specify the actual values.

I am running Sqoop version: 1.4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug for this, fixed in Sqoop 1.4.7

Fix is not straightforward. 
For example, for a column `col3=decimal(1,1)` one need to write `col3=decimal(1%2C1)`

Check [SQOOP-2103 issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2103) for more details.